# Transform + positioning issue in IE 11

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a position:fixed div in a modal on which bootstrap applied the transform:translate rule. It works fine in FF and Chrome but not showing up correctly in IE 11.

Here you can see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/roahda03/23/

This is the CSS:

```
    @import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
.modal-open .modal {
   //overflow: hidden;
 }
 .modal-body {
   height: calc(100vh);
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }

 #getFixed {
   position: relative;
   left: 10px;
   width: 500px;
 }
```

and the jquery applied at scroll

```
jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($('.modal-body').scrollTop() > 50)
    {
    $cache.css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'top': '0px',
        'left': '25px',
        'width': '500px'
      });
    }
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto',
        'left': '10px'
      });
  }
  $('.modal-body').scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

EDIT: this seems to be [a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806517/ie11-tramsform3d-and-position-fixed-problem). My question is how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have found a fine solution.

- Detect if browser used is **IE**
- Replace **css** top by `offset().top` of modal view top
- Replace **css** left by `offset().left` of `getFixed` id element

This work fine on all **IE** browser and other. Please try.

I have make a fiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lue2rsp/

```js
$('.launchConfirm').on('click', function (e) {
    $('#confirm').modal({
        show: true
    });
});

// variable for check if IE detected
var IfIE = false;  

//Check if IE used
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) 
{
  IfIE = true;
}
else  
{
  IfIE = false;
}


jQuery(function($) {
  function fixDiv() {
    var $cache = $('#getFixed');
    if ($('.modal-body').scrollTop() > 50)
    {
     if(IfIE == true){
     
       $cache.css({
          'position': 'fixed',
          'top': $(".modal-content").offset().top,
          'left':$("#getFixed").offset().left,
          'width': '500px'
        });
      }else{
       $cache.css({
          'position': 'fixed',
          'top': '0',
          'left':'25px',
          'width': '500px'
        });
      }
    }
    else
      $cache.css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': 'auto',
        'left': '10px'
      });
  }
  $('.modal-body').scroll(fixDiv);
  fixDiv();
});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
.modal-open .modal {
   //overflow: hidden;
 }
 .modal-body {
   height: calc(100vh);
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
 
 #getFixed {
   position: relative;
   left: 10px;
   width: 500px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="page-container">
    <div class="container">
        <br />
        <button type="button" class="btn launchConfirm">Open modal</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body" id="confirm2">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                 <div id="getFixed" style="background-color:red">This div should be fixed<br>in the modal, not outside it.</div>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                some random buttons
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```